# How can I handle database from Hierarchical data in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `Location` like this:

```
ID,   PID,   Location
1    NuLL    Country
2    1       City
3    2       County
4    3       District
5    4       Social
...  ...     ....
```

How can I handle my database in MySQL that returns this:

```
ID,   Location,   Full Location
1     Country     Country
2     City        City-Country
3     County      County-City-Country
4     District    District-County-City-Country
5     Social      Social-District-County-City-Country
...   ...         ...
```

Comment: Does your data only consist of a single chain, as suggested by the data in the question?  Or is it more complex?

Comment: Until now, my data consist a single chain. I'm very terrible about database, what do you mean about "more complex"? Simple example?

Comment: I think what is meant, do you have multiple parents or is Country the only parent (where `pid = null`)?  If you have multiple parents, are your expected results to show all parents and children, or just a specific parent/child?

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a single parent, then you can use this method which acts as a recursive query:

```
select id, location, @pid:=id as 'pid' ,
  @newlocation:=if(pid is null, 
                   location, 
                   concat_ws(',',@newlocation,location)) newlocation
from (select * from Location order by pid) t
  join (select @pid:=null, @newlocation:='') p 
     on coalesce(t.pid,0)=coalesce(@pid,0)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46ca6/1)

However, if you have multiple parents, this will only return one of those with its children.  It can be modified to work with a single parent/child combination, but not with multiple parents.

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with hierarchies is a tricky situation in the SQL world, in many cases programming languages offer better options to deal with this type of data - such as dictionaries and linked lists.

However, you can still achieve what you want by aliasing the table;

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Location, 
       CONCAT( 
          IF(ISNULL(t1.Location) , '', t1.Location)
        , IF(ISNULL(t2.Location) , '', CONCAT('-',t2.Location))
        , IF(ISNULL(t3.Location) , '', CONCAT('-',t3.Location))
        , IF(ISNULL(t4.Location) , '', CONCAT('-',t4.Location))
       ) as Full_Location
FROM Locations as t1
      left join Locations as t2 on t1.PID = t2.ID
      left join Locations as t3 on t2.PID = t3.ID
      left join Locations as t4 on t3.PID = t4.ID
```

This example assumes you only want to go four deep. It's possible to go deeper of course, just keep following the same structure.

There is a full write up on these hierarchical data and associated queries at http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html